# How to remove characters from string when string length is unknown

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5

I am taking input from textfield ,i has to extract the characters more than length 5. Then how to remove characters from text

Comment: An example of what you want to achieve will be helpful for us

Comment: In TableviewCell,in a custom label we can display upto 20 characters, so i have to extract the string more than 20 and display it in next label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this,

```
if(level_label.text.length>20)
    {
        NSString *str=[level_label.text substringFromIndex:20];
        // Place str in next_label.text
    }
```

Comment: Yes fine but, we have to get characters from above 20 as well,to display it in next label

Comment: str stores the characters above index 20 only

Comment: If level_label has 12345678901234567890qazwsxedc then str has 0qazwsxedc